# TradingView Pine-Script: Plot a line only if a input is true

Tags: if-statement, plot, pine-script

I want to plot some EMAs only if a input is true.. however when i use the if functions, it says "Cannot use 'plot' in local scope."

```html
//@version=4
study(title = "Todos os indicadores", overlay = true)
showemas        = input(false,          title = "Show EMAs")

if showemas == true
    plot(ema(close, length1), color=#F44336, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
    plot(ema(close, length2), color=#4CAF50, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
    plot(ema(close, length3), color=#673AB7, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
    plot(ema(close, length4), color=#2196F3, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
    plot(ema(close, length5), color=color.white, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
    plot(sma(close, length6), color=color.orange, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the condition in the `plot()` calls:

```
plot(showemas ? ema(close, length1) : na, color=#F44336, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
plot(showemas ? ema(close, length2) : na, color=#4CAF50, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
plot(showemas ? ema(close, length3) : na, color=#673AB7, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
plot(showemas ? ema(close, length4) : na, color=#2196F3, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
plot(showemas ? ema(close, length5) : na, color=color.white, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
plot(showemas ? sma(close, length6) : na, color=color.orange, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a great workaround